# Show Lock Screen Dialog on Android O

Tags: android, dialog, lockscreen, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I am able to successfully add a dialog to the lock screen on APIs prior to Oreo. It seems like google does not allow the flag `TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR` anymore from this API on.

Is there any way to show a dialog on lock screen on Android O?

---

Code that works for < Android O

```
int flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;

        int type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;

        WindowManager.LayoutParams windowLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                0,
                0,
                type,
                flags,
                PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

Comment: Did you every figure out a solution? Just stumbled on the same problem